# Echo strings when page is still downloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-get-contents

Im trying to make a PHP downloader.

```
echo '<p>Downloading New Update</p>';
$newUpdate = file_get_contents('http://your-server.com/update.zip');
echo 'Done downloading';
```

When I run the script (saying the zip takes long to download), the page loads until its fully downloaded and then shows the `Downloading New Update` and `Done downloading` at the same time.

What I want is to show the `Downloading New Update` before its finished downloading. When it is, `Done downloading` has to appear.

How can I combine this script with Ajax, Jquery, Javascript, in order to create a more dynamic downloader?

Comment: Create a div saying downloading updates at first and then use ajax to get the data and set the div text to Done Downloading. Simple

Comment: You can find some more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp. If you need further help just reply :)

Comment: Cant I use something like:`xmlhttp.open("GET","download_script.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();`  ??

Comment: That would work but you would need to elaborate on it if you want to display information to the user, @Peter K suggestion is an option without using JS/Ajax if you want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Simple flush might solve the task

```
echo '<p>Downloading New Update</p>';
flush();
$newUpdate = file_get_contents('http://your-server.com/update.zip');
echo 'Done downloading';
```

and you need to ensure this text is not inside the table.
Then browser should use progressive rendering and text should really apper.
The reason you need flush is that PHP doesn't actually send text from echo() to browser untill certain conditions are met, like script is finished or flush() is called explicitly